# Date picker error with Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I am using the [`simplecalendar.js`](https://code.google.com/p/antagon-cv-manager/source/browse/trunk/CVManagerWeb/WebContent/js/simplecalendar.js?spec=svn83&r=83) by Lea Smart But it does not seem to work with Mozilla. All the other browsers I have tested, ie, chrome and opera works but Mozilla gives error on this Condition:

```
if (browser.ns6) {
        var bTest = (e.pageX > parseInt(g_Calendar.containerLayer.style.left, 10) 
&& e.pageX < (parseInt(g_Calendar.containerLayer.style.left, 10) + 125) 
&& e.pageY < (parseInt(g_Calendar.containerLayer.style.top, 10) + 125) 
&& e.pageY > parseInt(g_Calendar.containerLayer.style.top, 10));
        if (e.target.name !== 'imgCalendar' && e.target.name !== 'month' 
&& e.target.name !== 'year' && e.target.name !== 'calendar' && !bTest) {
            g_Calendar.hide();
        }
    }
```

It calls

```
   window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
```

And shows the error any idea why this is not working with Mozilla?

Comment: what is the error msg which you are getting?